# How to format the JSON output to the desired format

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress

I am trying to create a custom controller for the WordPress JSON API plugin and so far everything is working except the JSON Data I have is not in the correct format.

This is my current JSON output:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "all_tags": {
    "tag-1": {
      "term_name": "Tag 1",
      "category_details": {
        "0": {
          "category_ID": 8,
          "category_name": "category 1",
          "category_count": 2
        },
        "2": {
          "category_ID": 13,
          "category_name": "category 2",
          "category_count": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "tag-2": {
      "term_name": "Tag 2",
      "category_details": [
        {
          "category_ID": 8,
          "category_name": "category 1",
          "category_count": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, in order to parse the data I **must have** the json data in a specific format. The correct format should be like this:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "all_tags": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "term_name": "Tag 1",
      "category_details": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "category_ID": 8,
          "category_name": "category 1",
          "category_count": 2
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "category_ID": 13,
          "category_name": "category 2",
          "category_count": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "term_name": "Tag 2",
      "category_details": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "category_ID": 8,
          "category_name": "category 1",
          "category_count": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how I am creating the array for the json:

```
<?php
...
$cats_all     = array(); // the array
if (!isset($cats_all[$custom_term->slug])) {

    // create the array

    $cats_all[$custom_term->slug] = array(
        'term_name' => $custom_term->name,
        'category_details' => array(
            array(
                'category_ID' => $categories[0]->term_id,
                'category_name' => $categories[0]->name,
                'category_count' => $mycats[0]->category_count
            )
        )
    );
} else {
    $cats_all[$custom_term->slug]['category_details'][] = array(
        'category_ID' => $categories[0]->term_id,
        'category_name' => $categories[0]->name,
        'category_count' => $mycats[0]->category_count
    );
}
...
// remove duplicates 
$input = $this->super_unique( $cats_all );
// return the array for json output by the plugin
return array(
    'all_tags' => $input,
);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Also the entire controller can be [viewed here](http://pastebin.com/raw/zREZsSp4).

Comment: How do you determine `count`, and `id` values? They don't seem to correspond to anything in your current JSON output. It also seems strange there should be duplicate `id` values...

Comment: @trincot I just used one of the plugin's default controller output to show how the structure should be and forgot to remove them.

Comment: OK, you removed `count`, what about the `id` values? Are they needed?

Comment: @trincot no they are not needed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need to achieve:

1. The `all_tags` value must be a sequential array, not an associative one. This you can achieve by taking the `array_values` at the last statement:

   ```
   return array(
       'all_tags' => array_values($input)
   );
   ```
2. The `category_details` values must be sequential arrays, not associative ones. This one is more tricky, as you actually ***do*** create them as sequential arrays, but the function `super_unique` will sometimes turn them into associative arrays, when it eliminates at least one duplicate. I suggest this fix to the function `super_unique` by adding two statements, around this one:

   ```
   $result = array_map( 'unserialize', array_unique( array_map( 'serialize', $array ) ) );
   ```

   To get this:

   ```
   $is_seq = end(array_keys($array)) == count($array)-1;
   $result = array_map( 'unserialize', array_unique( array_map( 'serialize', $array ) ) );
   if ($is_seq) $result = array_values($result);
   ```

   If you get an error on `end`, then you can use this for that line instead:

   ```
   end($array); $is_seq = key($array) == count($array)-1;
   ```

   The `$is_seq` variable checks that `$array` is sequential, and if so, calls `array_values` after the removal of the duplicates, which always returns a sequential array.

Comment: You're welcome. I added an alternative for the statement with `end` which could trigger an error. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem here is this:

```
       "0": {
          "category_ID": 8,
          "category_name": "category 1",
          "category_count": 2
        },
        "2": {
          "category_ID": 13,
          "category_name": "category 2",
          "category_count": 1
        }
```

if you want an array to be a json encoded array, indexes must be numeric and correlatives (0,1,2,3...)

Probably, after using your  $this->super_unique( $cats_all ), or inside this function, you should call array_values on every array that has been reindexed; it reset the values of the array to 0, 1, ... etc... and when encoded, it will be an array isntead of an object.

Generally speaking, it´s a good practice to use $array = array_values($array) after using array_filter(...) to correctly reindex the array, elsewhere, you can get indexes like 0,2,7... etc...

Let me know if you need more details